# "The C extension could not be compiled' error. - while installing Flask

Tags: python, flask

I get the error below when installing flask in virtualenv on debian 7. apt-get-install tells me I already have GCC. I tried `apt-get install libpcre3-dev` but then reinstalled flask with `pip install Flask-scss --force-reinstall -I` but still got the same error. How do I fix this so that the speedups are used?

The Error:

```
markupsafe/_speedups.c:12:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
==========================================================================
WARNING: The C extension could not be compiled, speedups are not enabled.
Failure information, if any, is above.
Retrying the build without the C extension now.


==========================================================================
WARNING: The C extension could not be compiled, speedups are not enabled.
Plain-Python installation succeeded.
==========================================================================
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to install the [`python-dev` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-dev) too; it depends on the right package that [contains `Python.h`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/i386/libpython2.7-dev/filelist):

```
apt-get install python-dev
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining that that is where the Python.h is found. It added to my learning. Also, the error is gone.

Comment: I now get the errors below, do I need to do anything about them?:

Answer (score 9):

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Or

```
 sudo apt-get install python3-dev for python3
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning python3-dev - life saver

Answer (score 1):

For those using Amazon Web Services (AWS) .

Install your system’s Development tool-chain per [this reference](http://wormbase.github.io/db-migration/dev/system-requirements.html):

**yum (Amazon AMI, RedHat, Centos)**

```
sudo yum groupinstall -y "Development Tools"
```

**apt (Debian, Ubuntu, Mint)**

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
```

Comment: would you know how to do this on MS Azure?

Comment: On Microsoft you need to install Mingw https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php so you can have gcc on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem on windows also when install libraries having c extensions. This problem in windows can be solved by install mingw, which stands for **Minimalist GNU for Windows**.

To install mingw for anaconda:

```
conda install mingw
```

To know more about mingw, have a look at http://www.mingw.org/